# Rig a character to an existing skeleton

Tags: rigging

I recently bought a game kit for unity which has rigged characters included.

After importing a character fbx in to Blender from a Unity fbx, I believe the characters were originally rigged in 3DS Max due to the bone naming. The skeleton is in the right order bone wise, but it looks all messed up in blender, which looks like a display issue.

I would like to use the same skeleton on a new character meshes.

Any idea how I could use the same skeleton, so it displays properly in blender and rig my character meshes?

Answer (score 0):

Rigs are not always compatible across multiple software applications. For instance, a control rig created in blender would need to be converted into a "game ready" rig before exporting it to function properly in unity.  A game ready rig tends to have far fewer bones than the control rigs created in blender and other 3D software for animations. Each software, while similar, has its own way of reading the information. It may be possible to constrain your current rig to a rig that blender recognizes for animations in blender that can be baked on the existing game ready rig for use in unity, however if you are unexperienced it may be very difficult for you to parent a new character to a copy of the existing rig with the proper weights.  There are many add-ons and tutorials out there that could help you with this process if you would like to learn more. One of my favorite resources is CGDive. Here is a link to one of the tutorial series but feel free to check them out on discord where you can ask questions related to rigging, find more information, and helpful add-ons.
https://youtu.be/INK__p3CWUw